# Is the VALS framework still relevant to market segmentation?

Tags: social-psychology, consumer-psychology

The [VALS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VALS) framework stands for

> ("Values, Attitudes And Lifestyles") [and] is a proprietary research
>   methodology used for psychographic market segmentation.

Is VALS still relevant, outdated or has it maybe been improved upon and taken a different form over the years?

I'm trying to streamline identifying the right consumer category for a product that is always different (real estate).

Comment: Did you even read the literature given in that Wikipedia article? From that literature it seems to me that you might want to consider taking a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I read the lterature then also followed the links provided. It seems the only piece of the missing puzzle is how the questions are weighted and there seems to be a small community working on it. I'm not quite at the 'answer this question' stage yet though.

Comment: As research shows, the psychometric approach of measuring personality (values, attitudes, lifestyle = personality) through self-report scales such as the VALS seems to not be very helpful in targeting your marketing activity because it does not significantly increase your sales. Rather you should observe actual buying behavior (similar to using cookies following online buyers around the web). So, to answer your question, no, the VALS is not longer relevant, and today (40 years later) marketers use completely different methods. The literature that I found from Wikipedia says so ...